# r filter rows based on number of occurrences within flexible time window

Tags: r, filter, time

The (simplified) situation is as follows: I have a dataframe with subjectID (grouping variable), sampleID (unique variable within each subjectID group) and sampleTime (time that sampleID was collected). I'd like to only filter those rows if at least 4 samples were collected within any given 4h period. For example, a sample could be included because one sample was collected 2hr prior to the current one, and two other samples 1hr and 2hr after the current one. Another example: a sample should not be included if the previous one was collected 5hr before the current one and the next three 1hr, 2hr, and 6hr after. The time window can be open on both sides and occasionally two samples can be collected at the exact same time.

While typing this question I found an answer that works in this simple case and shows my intention:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(6354363)

#create some data
df <- data.frame(subjectID = rep(paste0("ID", 1:4), each=20)) %>% 
  group_by(subjectID) %>% 
  mutate(time=sample(0:72, size=20, replace=T))  %>% 
  arrange(subjectID, time) %>% 
  mutate(sampleID = 1:20)

#create column incl to mark which rows to include
df <- df %>% group_by(subjectID) %>% 
  mutate(incl = case_when(time-lag(time, n=3) <= 4 ~ T,
                          lead(time, n=3) - time <= 4 ~ T,
                          lead(time, n=2) - lag(time, n=1) <= 4 ~ T,
                          lead(time, n=1) - lag(time, n=2) <= 4 ~ T)) 

#filter gives intended solution
df %>% filter(incl)
```

However, I feel this approach is unnecessarily convoluted and becomes too cumbersome in other situations, e.g. when I want at least 20 samples within a given time period, so I'm looking for a more generic solution. I tried looking into rollapply and other functions but no success yet. Is there a more elegant (and efficient) way to do this? I prefer a tidyverse solution but data.table could also work.

Comment: In those cases none of the samples would be included; `window = 1` (and a 'group size' of 4) would only lead to inclusion of samples if `time=1,1,2,2,3,4` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

df <- structure(list(subjectID = c("ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID4", "ID4", "ID4", "ID4", "ID4", "ID4", "ID4", "ID4", "ID4", "ID4", "ID4", "ID4", "ID4", "ID4", "ID4", "ID4", "ID4", "ID4", "ID4", "ID4"), time = c(2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 14L, 16L, 22L, 28L, 31L, 38L, 40L, 42L, 48L, 53L, 58L, 63L, 69L, 0L, 4L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 23L, 29L, 30L, 32L, 38L, 42L, 47L, 51L, 57L, 60L, 63L, 67L, 69L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 23L, 26L, 29L, 30L, 34L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 46L, 51L, 53L, 56L, 57L, 69L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 16L, 21L, 28L, 29L, 31L, 35L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 44L, 48L, 50L, 52L, 54L, 60L), sampleID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L), incl = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -80L), groups = structure(list(    subjectID = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4"), .rows = structure(list(        1:20, 21:40, 41:60, 61:80), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of",     "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .drop = TRUE))

tr <- 4 # Time range
gr <- 4 # Group range

df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    incl2 = c(diff(time), NA) %>%
      rollapply(gr-1, sum, fill = NA, align = "left") %>%
      `<=`(tr) %>%
      rollapply(., gr, any, na.rm = T, fill = ., align = "right")
  ) 

identical(df$incl, df$incl2)
#> [1] TRUE

df
#> # A tibble: 80 × 5
#> # Groups:   subjectID [4]
#>    subjectID  time sampleID incl  incl2
#>    <chr>     <int>    <int> <lgl> <lgl>
#>  1 ID1           2        1 TRUE  TRUE 
#>  2 ID1           2        2 TRUE  TRUE 
#>  3 ID1           5        3 TRUE  TRUE 
#>  4 ID1           5        4 TRUE  TRUE 
#>  5 ID1           6        5 TRUE  TRUE 
#>  6 ID1           7        6 TRUE  TRUE 
#>  7 ID1           9        7 TRUE  TRUE 
#>  8 ID1          14        8 FALSE FALSE
#>  9 ID1          16        9 FALSE FALSE
#> 10 ID1          22       10 FALSE FALSE
#> # … with 70 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>